# `root` owns some files in `/home/user` should I be concerned?

Tags: package-management, root, home-directory, dbus, ownership

```
$ sudo find /home/rick -user root 
/home/rick/.dbus
/home/rick/.dbus/session-bus
/home/rick/.dbus/session-bus/d7b25a27fe064cadb75a2f2f6ca7764e-0
/home/rick/.cache/dconf
/home/rick/.aptitude/config
/home/rick/.sane
/home/rick/.sane/xsane
/home/rick/.sane/xsane/xsane.rc
/home/rick/.packages
/home/rick/.config/gedit
/home/rick/.config/gedit/accels
```

`.sane` is the Brother scanner package that had to be installed using `sudo` so I'm not concerned. `gedit` I'm not concerned about.

What about `dbus` stuff and `.packages`? Should this be an area of concern or does everyone have that when they repeat the search command I used?

Comment: What was the reason for using `sudo find`? I use `find . '!' -user $USER -ls`. No `sudo`.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica It was a long time ago and I was just learning the `find` command. Actually I still learning it... Using your version I get: `find: ‘./.cache/dconf’: Permission denied` Which is why I guess I used `sudo` in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing in your home directory should be owned by root.  This happens when you run things with sudo (or gksudo).  Better change the ownership (and group) back to yourself.  Don't delete them (although that probably wouldn't be a problem).

Comment: Yes there is a good write-up on Super User about using sudo: https://superuser.com/questions/495937/should-root-ever-own-files-in-my-linux-home-directory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa I was more concerned about the specific file names `.dconf`, `.aptitude`, etc. For example `apt` almost always has to be run with `sudo` so how did it get there and should it simply be deleted or will it break things, etc.

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R rick ~/` to change ownership of everything in your home folder back.

Comment: You probably want to change *both* the owner and the group; adding to matalak's comment, use `sudo chown -R rick:rick ~/`