# Nautilus show hidden files

Tags: nautilus, reboot, settings

## Problem

Nautilus **hides** hidden files on reboot regardless of setting before rebooting.

## Expected

Nautilus keeps "show hidden" setting from before shutdown (in my case, always showing hidden files regardless of setting before shutdown is ok too).

## Question

**How to have Nautilus show hidden files after reboot without manually enabling "show hidden files" each time?**

## Debug info

```
{reboot}
$ gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-hidden-files
true
```

Open Nautilus (icon on dash) - hidden files not shown in Nautilus

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - hidden files shown in Nautilus

Close Nautilus window

Open Nautilus (icon on dash) - hidden files not shown in Nautilus (expected behaviour)

Nautilus --> Edit --> Preferences --> Show hidden and backup files

Hidden files now shown until reboot

Reboot

Open Nautilus (icon on dash) - hidden files not shown in Nautilus

Comment: Are you sure that permissions are OK for your dot-folders? If unsure - run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.*`.

Comment: Rather than using `gsettings` how about using Nautilus Edit Preferences menu for `Show hidden and backup files` option? Perhaps Nautilus has it's own configuration file.

Comment: @N0rbert I will test Vijay's answer first and then try your suggestion. Won't your command turn default root-owned directories like `~/.gvfs` to be owned by me? Will that cause further problems?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sorry I was not clear. I have tried `Nautilus --> Edit --> Preferences --> Show hidden and backup files` (using Nautilus Edit Preferences menu). The changes persist until reboot.

Comment: @tfstwbbnb Sorry I missed that. Before trying N0bert's comment first see if any files are owned by root in your home with `sudo find /home/$USER -user root`

Comment: For files owned by root in your home directory I wrote a question about this in May: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031303/root-owns-some-files-in-home-user-should-i-be-concerned

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The output is `/home/$USER/.config/PINCE`, `/home/$USER/.config/PINCE/PINCE.conf`, `/home/$USER/.gvfs` (replaced my username with `$USER`).  I'm not sure what `.gvfs` is for, but `PINCE` is probably from `gameconqueror`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition  to the `gsettings` key in the post, check if

```
gsettings get org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden
```

is false.

If it is false, run

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden true
```

Comment: I wonder how/why the value had been changed on my machine. It was working properly before. Running `gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden true` once allowed my "show hidden" to persist.

Comment: Even after running the `set` command, if I run the `get` command again it still shows `false`. It also prints `GLib-GIO-Message: 12:34:36.493: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.`