# Is it possible to permanently show hidden files?

Tags: nautilus, reboot, settings, hidden-files

Whenever I restart the OS or even after it locks, files are hidden again. I have selected to show hidden files numerous times but it always reverts back. I really have no desire to hide files and I spend a lot of times in hidden files. I have not been successful in making the setting persist at all.

I have tried using:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden true
```

But this eventually just returns to false.

Is this possible?

I have went through numerous topics of this same question here but very few discuss permanently toggling this. The only article that seems to have something useful was [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083759/nautilus-show-hidden-files) but it doesn't work either...

I'm thinking of writing a shell script to just run that command every 5 mins but I really don't want to go that route.

For some insight, I this is a problem on 3 different computers all different brands and 2 are custom. This doesn't persist on a fresh install with nothing installed yet. Since 20.04 was released, this has never worked, I have to show hidden files numerous times per day while I am working. I never had this issue with any other version asides from 20.04.

Comment: Hiding files is protecting you from yourself and I personally I  can not think of any reason to see all the hidden files all the time. Not an answer to your question but maybe something to think about.

Comment: @David While I understand the purpose of this feature, it is not needed for everyone nor should it be assumed we are not competent enough to have to be protected from ourselves; this is one of the reasons people use Linux. As I stated already, I work a lot in hidden files and this is not only unnecessary, it is beyond annoying since this used to be possible to show them permanently.

Answer (score 3):

For me selecting the GUI option did not stick even closing and re-opening the file manager would reset it to hidden. However this worked for me.

1. Close the file manager.
2. Edit `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini` and set `ShowHidden=true`.
3. Open the file manager, you'll notice the setting did not stick, so now select the `Show Hidden Files` option on the GUI.
4. Close the file manager.
5. Re-open the file manager, it should now show the hidden files.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.03, when relying on Show Hidden Files in the file manager would not persist.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu it's quite straightforward to show or hide hidden files persistently.

Open `Files` and then select the three line hamburger menu (arrow #1)

[image]

This will open the Nautilus menu

[image]

where you can check the option `Show Hidden Files`.

This will show hidden files as shown by arrow #2 (dot files and folders).

This setting persists after a system reboot.

If you wish to hide the files once more, just reverse the process.

[Additional reference](https://www.askingbox.com/question/linux-show-hidden-folders-and-files-permanently)

Comment: This is what I have been doing since 20.04 was released and it never persists after a reboot and it even resets itself during the day. This does not work at all and I have tried this on 3 different machines.

Comment: Strange as I am using 20.04 installed from scratch without modifications with the GNOME DE and do not experience the problem you outline. After obtaining the graphics for the answer I provided, I performed a reboot to check it out and the setting persisted.

Comment: Very strange indeed. I have this same issue on 3 machines too. I reported a bug to Ubuntu and am following that now. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: It does not persist in Ubuntu 21.10 for me. Have you found a solution?