# Environment seems to be broken

Tags: 16.04, proxy, xfce4-terminal

I tried using some code to reset my proxy back to all 0's. It seems that I didn't put in the proper variables and now my environment won't load

```
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "This script must be run as root";
  exit 1;
fi

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none' ;

grep PATH /etc/environment > lol.t;
cat lol.t > /etc/environment;

printf "" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies;

rm -rf lol.t;
```

I put this code in and now after I login all I get is a nice long look at my background, but nothing else. What do?

Comment: I suspect the issue may be that running `gsettings` with `sudo` has caused some personal settings files to become root-owned: try running `find ~ \( -user root -o -group root \) -ls` from a terminal (using Ctrl-Alt-F1 etc. to obtain a virtual terminal if you can't use a GUI terminal emulator) to identify any such

Comment: I put that in, now what should I be looking for? It also said that I'm denied permission from my .dbus

Comment: There really should be no root-owned files there - see [`root` owns some files in `/home/user` should I be concerned?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031303/root-owns-some-files-in-home-user-should-i-be-concerned)

Comment: I just got back from that and did what it said. The environment is still missing. What now?

Comment: Did you fix any ownership / permission issues?

Comment: I did, and even rebooted. But nothing changed other than the ownership.

Comment: Hello? Are you still there?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any other suggestions